# Use Apache MINA to create a reverse proxy server

Tags: apache-mina

I am trying to create a simple reverse-proxy server using Apache Mina. I found the `ServerProxyAcceptor` interface, and the SshServer class does have a `ServerProxyAcceptor proxyAcceptor` property with a setter, but I am not sure how to use it. I cannot find examples online as well.
Is there a way to use the Mina SshServer to create a simple reverse-proxy?